# Slack socket mode reconnecting

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I am running a JS application which uses bolt to connect to slack via socket mode.
I am running the application on a docker container and I noticed that the the socket mode connection disconnects after some time and reconnects on its own

I see below logs on the server, and no error. What could be the reason for the disconnection? I am missing some events between the time socket conection goes down and comes up.

```
[INFO]  socket-mode:SocketModeClient:0 Reconnecting to Slack ...
[INFO]  socket-mode:SocketModeClient:0 Going to establish a new connection to Slack 
[INFO]  socket-mode:SocketModeClient:0 Now connected to Slack
```

index.js

```
const app = new Slack.App({
    token: ,
    signingSecret: ,
    socketMode: true,
    appToken: ,
    extendedErrorHandler: true,

});
(async () => {
    // Start your app
    await app.start(3000);
    console.log('⚡️ Bolt app is running!');
})();
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@slack/bolt": "3.5",
    "@slack/rtm-api": "^6.1.0",
    "@slack/socket-mode": "^1.3.2",
    "@slack/web-api": "^6.8.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1"
  }
```